# Convert SQL datetime to show in input type datetime local

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

I have a datetime string which is being retrieved from controller in the following format:

```
dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a
3/1/2018 4:02:00 PM
```

I want to show it in input type `datetime-local`. So I need to convert the datetime in to this format:

```
yyyy-MM-DDTHH:mm
2018-01-03T16:02
```

I try to use this code at first which will give an output as js format then use a function to format it back. But it mistakenly read month as day and day as month. Which means the output will show like this `2018-03-01T16:02`.

```
var date_test = new Date("3/1/2018 4:02:00 PM".replace(/-/g,"/"));
```

Is there another way to convert this correctly?

Comment: Check out moment.js which is a great resource for formatting and manipulating dates.  https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know the format

```
dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a
3/1/2018 4:02:00 PM
```

why not just split the string correctly(date part and then time part)
and finally just create new date object using yyyy,MM,dd etc?

Answer (score 0):

Using moment.js.  Great library:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var dateString = "3/1/2018 4:02:00 PM";
var currentDate = moment(dateString, "M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss a");
document.write(currentDate.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm"))
</script>
```